# Error when downsampling: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index

Tags: python, pandas

After having split my imbalanced dataset in Python into test and training set, I wanted to subsample my data. However I get a very high accuracy, I also get the 
following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:33: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
```

Do I need to worry about this? In my dataset I have 2724 0's and 351 1's. The code I used downsample the data is the following:

```
df_majority = x_train[df_x.A==0]    
df_minority = x_train[df_x.A==1]    
df_majority_downsampled = resample(df_majority, replace=False, n_samples=351, random_state=123)    
df_downsampled = pd.concat([df_majority_downsampled, df_minority])
```

Sample data:

x     A      LA          LO

1     0      -42.3333.   72.4567

2     1      -42.4500    72.2345

3     0      -42.2345    72.0000

4     0      -42.9090    72.7897

5     0      -42.7777    72.1234

I want to predict A

Comment: Can you add data sample and expected output?

Comment: There is `df_x` and `x_train`, what DataFrame is sample in question? Can you add missing also?